# "Pause until" in workflow 2010

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, workflow

I have a problem on a client I have. The client contains a 2010 workflow in a hosted Sharepoint 2013, this workflow contains a break until a date that you enter. But that date being invalid because the break is taking too long, eg 30 minutes delayed.

[image]

I need your help to get an idea to solve this large margin of error. Prioritize break, or take this delay.

I thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a pause until step you could use a custom timer job, this has the advantage of not having to leave workflows hanging on pause steps for extended periods of time.

Add a hidden number column to your list and leave it blank.

Change the pause step to change value of number column to 1.

end workflow

Have timer job that runs on all items where number column is 1

Timer job initiates second workflow (the steps that occur after the pause)

Add a step to change number column to some non 1 number